# Override inline css

Tags: css, wordpress, content-management-system

WordPress theme I am using has some inline css in the header and one of the things I am trying to change is the header top/bottom padding. In the inline css its listed as:

```
    <head>
    ...
        <style type="text/css" data-type="vc_custom-css">
        #site-header:not(.shrink) .site-title { padding: 60px 0 !important; }
        </style>
    </head>

<body class="home page page-id-24236 page-child parent-pageid-5 page-template-default logged-in admin-bar wpb-js-composer js-comp-ver-4.12.1 vc_responsive customize-support">
    <div id="page" class="layout-fullwidth">
        <div id="site-header-wrapper">
            <header id="site-header" class="site-header" role="banner">
                <div class="container container-fullwidth">
                <div class="header-main logo-position-left header-layout-fullwidth header-style-3">
                <div class="site-title">                                
                    <h1><a href="#" rel="home"></h1>    
                </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Obliviously, **#site-header:not(.shrink) .site-title {... !important}** is not going to work in my styles.css.

I have tried the following and it still doesn't work:

```
[style]#site-header:not(.shrink).site-title { padding: 1px 0 !important; }
```

How do I get it to override?

Comment: Don't you hate inline styles? They really stink.  I'll post an answer momentarily....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style blocks that aren't from the stylesheet stink.  I truly despise it when theme developers put them in their theme.  The only thing worse is inline styles (ie `<div style="padding: 5px !important;">`).  Those are virtually impossible to overcome.

In your case, there's a couple of hack-tastic way to overcome this hacky issue.

In your child theme's functions.php file, you can use the following (Admittedly hacky) solution:

```
// We're adding a HIGH priority of 9999 which should cause this to be output AFTER the theme's bad styles.
add_action('wp_head', 'fix_bad_theme_styles', 9999);

function fix_bad_theme_styles() { ?>
    <style type="text/css" data-type="vc_custom-css">
            #site-header:not(.shrink) .site-title { padding: 1px 0 !important; }
    </style>
<?php }
```

If that doesn't work, an even hackier way would be to put the style in the footer.  It'll work, but it's not best-practice (as if any of this solution is!):

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'fix_bad_theme_styles');
```

Comment: You, my friend are awesome. I have tried everything in the book via CSS.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using a child theme you can override a specific file e.g. `footer.php`

So you would create a file of the same name in the same directory and copy over the code you need

Answer (score 0):

Try adding more specificity to your rule, like:

body .anotherParentClass #site-header:not(.shrink).site-title { padding: 1px 0 !important; }

```
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/robsilva/wx113Lxo/
```

Comment: I tried a few different was but no luck. I just added more of the code from the template to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a space between `.site-title` and `:not` part. Try this instead :

```
#site-header:not(.shrink) .site-title { padding: 1px 0 !important; }
```

Comment: Tried. Not going to work. the inline style in the header has !important in it.